# Load url using click() jquery

Tags: jquery

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    //alert('hi');
    $('#call1').click(function(){

        $.('#text').load('click1.html')
    })   

    $('#call2').click(function(){

        $.('#text').load('click2.html')
    })  

    $('#call3').click(function(){

        $.('#text').load('click3.html')
    })      
})
```

HTML

```
<div id="call1">click 1</div>
<div id="call2">click 2</div>
<div id="call3">click 3</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="text">sdfsdfs</div>
```

I want to load html pages in `#text` when user clicks `#call1`, `#call2`, or `#call3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `$('#text')` instead of `$.('#text')` :)